# .decode('hex') Python2.7 vs Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which in Python 2.7 works exactly how I want. It takes a series of integer values in regs and converts each value to its character equivalent. For example, 21365 ==> 0x5375 amd would result in "Su".

```
RegString = ""
    for i in range(length):
        if regs[start+i]!=0:
            print (" Regs is ", regs[start+1], " Hex  is ", hex(regs[start+i]), " Striped is ", str(format(regs[start+i],'x') ))
            RegString = RegString + str(format(regs[start+i],'x').decode('hex'))
```

However in Python 3, the decode('hex') throws an error.  Now, I looked at many posting with this  problem, but have not been able to apply those solutons to my problem, that is to modify the above code to work in Python 3.

Here is the output when I try to run this section of code:

> Regs is  20341  Hex  is  0x4f75  Striped is  4f75
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "v3Test.py", line 23, in Get_Regester_String
>       RegString = RegString + str(format(regs[start+i],'x').decode('hex'))
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix the above failing statement so that it will work in Python 3.7 "***RegString = RegString + str(format(regs[start+i],'x').decode('hex'))***
".  Thanks...RDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3 use the following process

```
bytes.fromhex(format(regs[start+i],'x')).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I worked on this for several hours before I posted the question.  Your answer works like a champ and a lot simpler that some  of the things I tried.  Bravo